# Bash / xargs trick to open all files that changed in git HEAD

Tags: git, bash, xargs

I open files from Terminal in Sublime Text and do so using a shortcut like this:

`$ subl <filename>`

...what I'm hoping to do is open all files that changed in my last git commit.

I can see all files that changed like so:

```
$ git show --name-only HEAD
commit b2c891f64daab0dc67df5cde9608602c7cde2f7b
Author: Jacob
Date:   Fri Jun 9 16:52:05 2017 -0700

    start doing some cool stuff; ref 12345

python/deep/hot/Classes.py
python/shallow/cold/features.tmpl
javascript/utility_master.js
```

... but this command shows more info besides the filenames themselves.

I want to do something like:

`$ git show --name-only HEAD | <get the lines out that aren't filenames> | xargs -i subl {}`

Does this require `awk`? Or a different `git` flag that I can't find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use diff: `git diff --name-only HEAD~`

`` subl `git diff --name-only HEAD~` ``

Comment: @JacobIRR: the tilde syntax is followed by a number, and means "count back that many iterations across first-parents". The number defaults to one, so whatever~ = whatever~1 = "one commit earlier, using first-parent links only", where "first parent only" doesn't matter because we're only going one anyway. See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

`git show --pretty= --name-only HEAD` should do the trick